# How do I loop over a longer list with map that depends on a shorter list wrapping it to apply some function to the longer list in Common Lisp?

Tags: loops, functional-programming, mapping, lisp, common-lisp

Basically, I'd like the equivalent of this code in Common Lisp, but in a preferably more convenient way.

```
(defun circular (items) 
  (setf (cdr (last items)) items))
```

```
(map 'list #'(lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 
     (circular '(1 2 3)) '(2 3 4 5))
;; ==> (3 5 7 6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is almost good enough.
(The only problem is that you [should **not** modify a quoted list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm)).

All you need to do is to restore the list you made circular:

```
(defun map-circular (result-type function governing-sequence &rest reused-lists)
  "Apply `function` to successive sets of arguments in which one argument is obtained from each sequence.
The result has the length of `governing-sequence`."
  (let ((last-cells (mapcar (lambda (list)
                              (let ((cell (last list)))
                                (setf (cdr cell) list)
                                cell))
                            reused-lists)))
    (unwind-protect
         (apply #'map result-type function governing-sequence reused-lists)
      (dolist (cell last-cells)
        (setf (cdr cell) nil)))))
```

Test:

```
(defparameter l1 (list 1 2))
(defparameter l2 (list 1 2 3))
(map-circular 'list #'+ '(1 2 3 4) l1 l2)
==> (3 6 7 7)
l1
==> (1 2)
l2
==> (1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SERIES package, you can use the SERIES function which:

> Creates an infinite series that endlessly repeats the given items in
> the order given.

This works if the items are known statically, ie. not from a list of values given at runtime.

Here below, the code scans a list and, at the same time, iterates over the infinite serie 1 2 3 .... Both series are iterated in parallel with `mapping`, as `s` and `n`, and mapping generates a series of `(cons s n)`. The result is collected as a list:

```
(collect 'list
  (mapping ((s (scan 'list '(a b c d e f g h)))
            (n (series 1 2 3)))
    (cons s n)))
```

The result is:

```
((A . 1) (B . 2) (C . 3) (D . 1) (E . 2) (F . 3) (G . 1) (H . 2))
```

Series are subject to stream-fusion, and the expanded code is:

```
(let* ((#:out-823 (list 1 2 3)))
  (let (#:elements-816
        (#:listptr-817 '(a b c d e f g h))
        #:items-821
        (#:lst-822 (copy-list #:out-823))
        #:items-826
        (#:lastcons-813 (list nil))
        #:lst-814)
    (declare (type list #:listptr-817)
             (type list #:lst-822)
             (type cons #:lastcons-813)
             (type list #:lst-814))
    (setq #:lst-822 (nconc #:lst-822 #:lst-822))
    (setq #:lst-814 #:lastcons-813)
    (tagbody
     #:ll-827
      (if (endp #:listptr-817)
          (go series::end))
      (setq #:elements-816 (car #:listptr-817))
      (setq #:listptr-817 (cdr #:listptr-817))
      (setq #:items-821 (car #:lst-822))
      (setq #:lst-822 (cdr #:lst-822))
      (setq #:items-826 ((lambda (s n) (cons s n)) #:elements-816 #:items-821))
      (setq #:lastcons-813 (setf (cdr #:lastcons-813) (cons #:items-826 nil)))
      (go #:ll-827)
     series::end)
    (cdr #:lst-814)))
```

If you need to pass an arbitrary list to the function, you can make your own circular list by calling `(nconc list list)`, which is simpler to write. Since you probably don't want to mutate the input list, you can write this instead:

```
(defun circularize (list)
  (let ((list (copy-list list)))
    (nconc list list)))
```